# Can a character using a Cloak of the Gargoyle use line-of-sight psionic effects?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, powers, psionics

If a character who has turned to stone by using a Cloak of the Gargoyle detects an ally nearby using tremorsense, can he still communicate them with a telepathy power that requires line of sight/effect?

Similarly, if this character has the Psionic Spark wild talent (one object within close burst 5 that you can see can be set of fire), can he still use it while in stone form, via tremorsense, on an object on the floor in front of him, or behind him (without moving, obviously)?

Comment: Also, where are the rules for the Petrified condition? I can't seem to find it in the glossary at the back of my handbooks

Comment: Petrification and the Cloak are quite different things, and asking about both would be asking two questions at once. I've edited this to be only about the specific magic item. You can afloat about petrification in its own question.

Comment: I wasn't able to check what the petrification rules were to see if they were different to the effects of the item.

Comment: That's OK. You just need to ask about your specific problem and then let the answering experts decide if other things are relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Cloak of the Gargoyle](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3560) specifically says on its power the following:

> You can take actions only to spend your second wind or to end this effect (a minor action).

[Speaking is a free action](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=654), so, no. You can't communicate with anyone while in stone form.

About your comment question, Rules Compendium (pg 232) have the full description of the [Petrified](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=140) condition. It also appear on Player's Handbook (pg 277), but the RC version is the current rules for this effect.

It is also worthy of notice that the Cloak of the Gargoyle do not apply the Petrified condition on the user. It gives them a unique effect that has the appearance of being turned to stone.